# C# Monogame, trying to create a 2D racing AI

Tags: c#, artificial-intelligence, 2d, monogame, topdown

So I have been tasked in making a 2D top-down racing game over the summer for college, and I have been dreading doing the AI but it is finally time. I have googled many different ways of the same thing just to try and find a person asking the same question but it seems everyone uses Unity over Monogame.

So I have an "enemy" car which can accelerate (as in slowly speeds up to top speed), decelerate and steer left and right. I have got the actual car the player drives working fine but the game is boring when the player isn't racing against anyone. All I need is a very basic AI which will follow a path around the course and will readjust if it gets knocked or something happens to it. I don't even know where to start, **Please help**!!! Please let me know if you need any more details.

Comment: Should the AI car do complex tasks like learn from mistakes? Or simply perform steering and acceleration tasks? The former would require substantially more effort and frameworks than the latter, I think.

Comment: Jacob K it needs to be able to drive around the track and if it gets nudged by the player's car then it should keep going following the track even if its gone off course. There any obstacles in the way of the enemy except for the player. Also, i forgot to mention there is a "boost" that the player and enemy can use to speed up temporarily. It takes 3 seconds to charge up once its been recharged, and the enemy AI also needs to know the best places to boost e.g. the straights of the track

Answer (score 1):

I may be misunderstanding your question, but it does not seem like you are looking for AI capabilities in your enemy car.... "All I need is a very basic AI which will follow a path around the course and will readjust if it gets knocked or something happens to it.". AI typically implies learning, but no where does it seem that you need your car to learn from past mistakes/"experiences". It sounds like you can use a path-finding algorithm to solve your problem since you have no requirement of the car actually learning from previous interactions with other cars, fields, etc. A super popular algorithm you can look into is A*. You can set up your game to be a graph with edges that have the "boosts" be lower weighted then the common "road". The obstacles or path-finding equivalent term - walls can be represented as high weight edges which would cause your car to avoid them automatically, by nature of A* finding the fastest path to a point.

AStar explanation with pseudo code: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A*_search_algorithm

Great visualizer tool: https://qiao.github.io/PathFinding.js/visual/

**Accelerating/Decelerating**

As for accelerating/decelerating that can be separate logic like randoms deciding whether to speed up or not.

**If it gets knocked or something happens to it**

You can re-calculate the A* when the car is hit to ensure that your car gets the new fastest path to get back on course. The actual collision logic is up to you (not part of the A* algo).

Note that if you are planning to have more than just a straight path in which the cars can steer (meaning there is no crazy bends or turns) the A* should not have too much variation from the natural algorithm. If you are planning to support that kind of track you may need to look into slightly different algorithms, because you will need to keep track of the rotated angle of your car.

Comment: Thank you for you reply. The visualizer tool is really good to know how it works, however I don't really know how to implement any of it. https://imgur.com/a/qK5B6jV is this what you mean by making a graph for it? I'm not sure how I would implement this into the game...  EDIT: then I could weight the edges with the approximate distance of the edge? and then if edge>certaindistance the enemy car boosts

Comment: Imagine representing your game as a 2D array. Where let's say every 10 pixels is a "spot" or item in the array. Each cell then has a "connection" or edge to the next cell that holds 1 key item: the weight to get from itself to that edge. The weight would then depend on what kind of cell it is. For example if your standard weight is 5 from one regular cell to another, then to represent that you would want your algorithm to try and maximize how many boosts it uses then you can make weights to those edges 2 or 3. "Graphs" are an abstract idea; this is one of the many implementations you can do.

Comment: Ok, so you mean I should have an array like this? https://imgur.com/a/OGm79i0 (The numbers being placeholders for the weights of the edges). So the places that are out of bounds should be not weighted (0)? Sorry if I seem like a beginner in this because I am. :P So each node in the "nodes" array represents an area of the map e.g. 30x30 pixels? EDIT: so if the enemies car is a specific node, all the nodes adjacent to that node are compared to see which node has the least weight, and so on?

Comment: I would make several classes to accomplish this goal. You can make a Node class which would contain some value like the tile type (as well as all the A* data you will need) or whatever else you need to store. You can also make an Edge class which would have two Nodes inside of it (a start and end) as well as a double representing the weight between the two nodes. Your 2D array would be of the Nodes. You can automatically generate the edge connections while looping through the array in some initialize function.

Comment: Ok, what do you mean by "tile type"? And what properties would be stored in the Node class, and the Edge class? (and I understand that the 2D array would be List<Node> nodes = new List<Node>();).

Comment: Tile type can just be an enum representing different tiles you have. As for the node and edge I told you in the previous comment what you would need... If you don't understand please watch a video on graphs and pathfinding and re-read the comment

Answer (score 0):

What you need to implement would be dependent on how complex, of course, your AI needs to be. If all it needs to do is readjust its steering and monitor its speed, a basic AI car could at a given time step...

1. Accelerate if not at top speed
2. Decelerate if cooling down from a boost
3. Steer away from the track boundaries
4. Decide whether or not to boost

(1) and (2) are easy enough to implement at a given time interval. Something like `if(speed < maxSpeed) { accel(); } else if(speed > maxSpeed) { decel(); }` where a `double maxBoostSpeed` exists to limit speed during a boost.

(3) and (4) could be achieved by drawing a trajectory in front of the car with something like `[ x + speed*Math.cos(angle), y + speed * Math.sin(angle) ]`. Then (3) could be achieved by steering towards the center of the track, and (4) could be from projecting the trajectory into a line and finding the distance before the next track boundary a.k.a. the next turn. If that distance to the trajectory intersection is large, it may be time to boost.

Comment: Thanks for your reply but I have now realised they want me to implement a "high level algorithm" e.g. A* or other pathfinding algorithms. This would've worked just find tho ;(